# When I apply the .Distinct my list flips values for each row?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var gridInfo = (from leader in db.LeaderAdminAccesses
                join emp in db.Employees
                on leader.ID equals emp.DPSID
                select new { ID = leader.ID, NAME = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName }).Distinct();



var temp = gridInfo.Select(x => new List<string> { x.ID, x.NAME }).ToArray();
```

When I look at `gridInfo` before `temp` (in debugger) I see a list like this:

> 0 {ID="123",NAME="John Smith"}
>
> 1 {ID="234",NAME="Jane Doe"}

When I view `temp` I see it like this?

> [0] Count = 2
>
> ```
>     [0] "123"
>     [1] "John Smith"
> ```
>
> [1] Count = 2
>
> ```
>     [0] "Jane Doe"
>     [1] "234"
> ```

I should note that this does not occur if I leave out the `.Distinct()`

Why is it doing this?  And what do I do so it doesn't return like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "flips values"? What output did you expect?

Comment: @CoryNelson if you look at temp you will see what I'm referring too.  The 0 element for Jane Doe should be the id value (234) and the 1 element should be her name.

Comment: I don't think this is plain-old LINQ - is this LINQ-to-SQL we're talking about? If so, can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: @TimRogers - It is LINQ-to-Entity/LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: @ConradFrix - Do you want me to show you a screenshot?  IDK what to tell you... :)

Comment: gridInfo is an IQueryable then? I had no idea `new List{}` worked when generating SQL. Try adding an `AsEnumerable()` after the `Distinct()`.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a specific type, even an anonymous one, than using a two value list for key value pairs.

Comment: @webdad3 You might want to add that to the question then. It matters a lot.

Comment: @CoryNelson - That worked...  Why did that work?  What does AsEnumerable in this situation?

Comment: @webdad3 oh never mind I see now that that is the output of gridinfo

Comment: @webdad3 Can you look at the raw SQL that is executed with and without `AsEnumerable()`? Would love to see how `new List<string> { x.ID, x.NAME }` got translated into SQL... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is executing as a SQL statement. Without an order-clause, the order of rows is not deterministic in any SQL statement. You probably want to do this kind of post-processing with the data in memory.

```
var temp = gridInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new List<string> { x.ID, x.NAME }).ToArray();
```

`AsEnumerable()` signifies that you want to process the remainder of the query in memory, not as a SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, that answer was verify helpful